# Show that rank of a matrix is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that row rank of a matrix is the number of row vectors that span row space of the matrix. Column rank can be similarly defined.

I also know that row rank = column rank and have learned the proof from the book of linear algebra written by Atindra Mohun Gun.

But will this proof of row rank and column rank be sufficient to show that rank of a matrix is unique ?

Comment: show that if matrix has rank a and b then a = b for all a and b

Comment: "I know that row rank of a matrix is the no of row vectors that span row space of the matrix." No, this is wrong as it is stated.

Comment: Once one proves that *the* row rank of a given matrix is the same as its column rank, one *defines* the rank of the matrix as its row rank (which is the same as its column rank).

Answer (score 0):

Before we can talk about matrix rank, we have to talk about row rank, which is the dimension of row space of the matrix. You should have proven that row rank is unique.

Similarly, column rank is unique.

From the result that row rank is equal to column rank, we can then talk about matrix rank. Of which, the uniqueness is due to uniqueness of row rank.

Answer (score 0):

1. You know the definition of row **rank** of a matrix.
2. You know the definition of column **rank** of a matrix.
3. You prove that row **rank** of a matrix=column **rank** of a matrix.
4. Now you define **rank** of a matrix=column **rank** of a matrix.

Then by definition it is **unique**.